# Android: How to select some object (e.g. car, person) on photo?

Tags: android, image, photo

I want to cut from picture some object, for example there is a picture of street and I need to save only car (without background). Is any simple way to select it? Like magic wand in photoshop?

Mobile application, android.

Comment: I suggest you use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798895) for coding